# Can't connect to IPsec/L2TP on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, opensuse, ipsec

I want to access VPN network from my laptop, which runs OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. The problem is that I can't connect with neither NetworkManager, neither configuring anything manually.

Logs provided:

```
● strongswan.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/strongswan.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-08-16 18:49:55 EEST; 1min 6s ago
Process: 3163 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipsec start --nofork (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 3163 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon ldap pkcs11 aes des blowfish rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt af-alg fips-prf gmp curve25519 agent xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm curl soup attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default farp stroke vici smp updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-sim-pcsc eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-simaka-pseudonym eap-simaka-reauth eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam tnc-imc tnc-imv tnc-tnccs tnccs-20 tnccs-11 tnccs-dynamic dhcp certexpire led duplicheck radattr addrblock unity counters
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: 06[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'myvpn'
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: 06[CFG] added configuration 'myvpn'
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec_starter[3163]: charon stopped after 200 ms
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: charon stopped after 200 ms
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec[3163]: ipsec starter stopped
Aug 16 18:49:55 linux-u9yv ipsec_starter[3163]: ipsec starter stopped

● xl2tpd.service - Level 2 Tunnel Protocol Daemon (L2TP)
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/xl2tpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-16 18:49:26 EEST; 1min 45s ago
Main PID: 3216 (xl2tpd)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/xl2tpd.service
        └─3216 /usr/sbin/xl2tpd -D

Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv systemd[1]: Started Level 2 Tunnel Protocol Daemon (L2TP).
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: Using l2tp kernel support.
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.10 started on linux-u9yv PID:3216
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
Aug 16 18:49:26 linux-u9yv xl2tpd[3216]: xl2tpd[3216]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d
         └─NetworkManager-ovs.conf
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-16 18:47:45 EEST; 3min 34s ago
Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
Main PID: 1539 (NetworkManager)
Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
        ├─1539 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
        └─2359 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-965cfe14-cccd-410b-8d8a-1104dd6cb0e4-wlp2s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp2s0.conf wlp2s0

Aug 16 18:49:58 linux-u9yv NetworkManager[1539]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Aug 16 18:49:58 linux-u9yv charon[3512]: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv ipsec_starter[3511]: child 3512 (charon) has quit (exit code 0)
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv ipsec_starter[3511]: 
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv ipsec_starter[3511]: charon stopped after 200 ms
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv ipsec_starter[3511]: ipsec starter stopped
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv nm-l2tp-service[3455]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv NetworkManager[1539]: <info>  [1534434599.0752] vpn-connection[0x55d60f06c300,435a9c8a-2875-43bf-b20a-5a3af13ee4de,"test",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv NetworkManager[1539]: <info>  [1534434599.0818] vpn-connection[0x55d60f06c300,435a9c8a-2875-43bf-b20a-5a3af13ee4de,"test",0]: VPN service disappeared
Aug 16 18:49:59 linux-u9yv NetworkManager[1539]: <warn>  [1534434599.0842] vpn-connection[0x55d60f06c300,435a9c8a-2875-43bf-b20a-5a3af13ee4de,"test",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

**EDIT:** The problem is not on server side since I can connect to my VPN using Windows, Android and Ubuntu devices.

Answer (score 0):

You would get better log output using `sudo journalctl` than using `systemctl status` for strongswan and xl2tpd as NetworkManager-l2tp starts its own instances with custom config files.

You might even need to stop the system xl2tpd service, see "Issue with not stopping system xl2tpd service" in the package's README.md file :

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/blob/master/README.md

As mentioned in the following bug reports, Tumbleweed needs the xl2tpd package to be updated to work with newer kernels :

- https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1094808
- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/issues/86

The second link has a workaround by building xl2tpd from source code.